# Mean Y for individual X values

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data set in .dta format with height and weight of baseball players. I want to calculate the mean height for each individual weight value.
From what I've been able to find, I could use dplyr and "group_by", but my R script does not recognize the command, despite having installed and called the package.

Thanks!

Comment: then u do `base R` methods i.e. `aggregate` i.e `aggregate(height~weight, df1, mean)` or `with(df1, tapply(height, weight, FUN = mean))`

Comment: @DespeRate - what error message(s) do you receive when you use `dplyr`?

Comment: Aggregate did it! @akrun

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example coded in base R using baseball player height and weight data obtained from the [UCLA SOCR MLB HeightsWeights](http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_Data_MLB_HeightsWeights#References) data set.

After cleaning the data (weight is missing for one player), I posted it to GitHub to make it accessible without having to clean it again.

```
theCSVFile <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/datasciencedepot/gh-pages/data/baseballPlayers.csv"
download.file(theCSVFile,"./data/baseballPlayers.csv",method="curl")
theData <- read.csv("./data/baseballPlayers.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
aggData <- aggregate(HeightInInches ~ WeightInPounds,mean,
                 data=theData)
head(aggData)
```

...and the output is:

```
> head(aggData)
  WeightInPounds HeightInInches
1            150       70.75000
2            155       69.33333
3            156       75.00000
4            160       71.46667
5            163       70.00000
6            164       73.00000
>
```

regards,

Len